How to disable public IP in AWS ECS fargate instances
Due to the new costs implemented by AWS in terms of charging for the use of public IPs that are dynamically assigned to operational Elastic Container Service Fargate instances past February.

https://community.aws/content/2c6cKl0W4KQZIO6dWnnDHs1tHSp/aws-to-charge-public-ipv4-addresses

I need solutions to be able to avoid this over cost involved in charging for the use of these IPs.
I have tried a few solutions with no luck:

https://medium.com/@eldhomaniabraham/enabling-or-disabling-public-ip-for-ecs-fargate-instances-in-aws-1552cbd365dc
https://www.cloudkeeper.com/insights/blog/how-optimize-vpc-endpoint-amazon-ecr-images
https://www.reddit.com/r/aws/comments/g47lj5/avoiding_ecr_costs_natprivatelink/

Edit:
The main problem is that disabling public IPs you lose access to, for example, the AWS image repository (ECR) and the ECS fargate instances do not start even though they are all inside the same VPC.
Other options such as generating a VPC endpoints to use the AWS internal network to access the image repository (ECR). But after following all the steps, the Fargate instances do not have access to the ECR either.
On the other hand, the only connections of those ECS fargate instances are to the image repository and to the Database (RDS).
There is an alternative by creating a NAT Gateway but the traffic has a higher cost than the cost of the public IPs so it would not save these costs that we want to avoid or reduce.
I hope you can help me.
Thanks in advance.
Best regards.

Can you elaborate on your problem or the outcome you want to achieve? In the question you already provide the answer (medium article on how to disable the public ip). I assume you still have to talk to or get called by the internet, so just disabling the public ip on fargate without any replacement is not an option.

You need to describe in detail what specifically about those different solutions did not work for you. Just disabling the public IP assignment to Fargate instances is trivial, so what is the actual issue you are running into?

Thank you for your fast answer, I've edited adding some appreciations of the solutions tested.

It sounds like you created VPC endpoints for ECR, but the tasks still failed to start. That should work, so if it doesn't work for you, you need to include in your question the exact error message you see in the ECS service console. Note that you have to create VPC endpoints for the ECR, S3 and ECS services to run ECS tasks without Internet access: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/setting-up-aws-privatelink-for-amazon-ecs-and-amazon-ecr/

I will try it again. I know I created only one endpoint to ECR. I am going to study your advice and I hope reply with news soon.Thank you Mark.

Hi @MarkB, I have some problems with the configuration that you sent in last message.  The specific problem when I try to create the first ECR Endpoint is that, the documentation require a Security Group that be applied to all ECS instances. I don't known how I can do this because each ECS Service has own security group.  In other words, there is not  only one Security Group, there are one Security Group by ECS service. There is 3 clusters with ten ECS services more or less and those respective security groups.

The documentation is just giving an example. You can have multiple security groups in use in ECS, you just have to allow traffic from all those security groups in the security group assigned to the VPC endpoint. Or if that's a problem, just allow all traffic from your VPC's CIDR block in your VPC endpoint's security group.

Thanks, I am going to  allow all traffic. I thought that it would not a best practise to allow all traffic but there is more than forty SG.

Hi @MarkB, I created the six endpoints like configuration show. Then, I disable the public IP of one ECS service and I restarted the task. Finally, I got this error: " CannotPullContainerError: ref pull has been retried 5 time(s): failed to copy: httpReadSeeker: failed open: failed to do request: Get XXXX.dkr.ecr.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/image-repository-example:image-example: dial tcp 1.2.3.4:443: i/o timeout". It seems that the ECS service, without public IP can not access to ECR to pull the image.

You haven't configured the VPC endpoints correctly if you are getting that error.

Do you have DNS Support and DNS Hostnames enabled on the VPC?

Both configurations are checked or enabled in the VPC configuration. Therefore, according to your given answer, the problem must be in the endpoints configuration.
